# How do I randomly draw an object from a Variable?

Tags: python

I'm making a card game for a school project, specifically "War". Each round a card should be randomly picked from my "Ranks" and "Suits" variables, but I get the same card each time (I'm very loosely following a tutorial). How can I make the output be randomized each time?

````
import random

ranks = ["Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
suits = ["Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds","Spades"]
deck = []

value = 1
for rank in ranks:
    for suit in suits:
        deck.append([rank + " of " + suit, value])
    value = value + 1

random.shuffle(deck)
score = 26
c1 = deck.pop(0)
c2 = deck.pop(0)
c11 = deck.pop(5)
c22 = deck.pop(7)
while True:
  choice = input ("Press enter to play war")
  print("Your score is", score)
  print("")
  print("")
  print("Your card is:" + " ",c1[0])
  print("")
  print("")
  print("")
  print("Enemy card is", c2[0])
  if c2[1] > c1[1]:
    score = score - 1
    print("Enemy win! Score subtracted by a card!")
  if c1[1] > c2[1]:
    score = score + 1
    print("Player win! Enemy score subtracted by a card!")
  if c1[1] == c2[1]:
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("WAR!")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    choice = input("Click enter to draw four cards, one face up")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Your card is:" + " ", c11[0])
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Enemy card is", c22[0])
if c22[1] > c11[1]:
  score = score - 4
print("")
print("War lost!")
print("")
if c22[1] < c11[1]:
  score = score + 4
  print("")
  print("War lost!")
  print("")
if score <= 52:
  quit()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to pick a new card every time, which means you have to move choosing cards to inside the loop:

```
while True:
  c1 = deck.pop(0)
  c2 = deck.pop(0)
  c11 = deck.pop(5)
  c22 = deck.pop(7)

  choice = input ("Press enter to play war")
  print("Your score is", score)
  print("")
  print("")
  print("Your card is:" + " ",c1[0])
  print("")
  print("")
  print("")
  print("Enemy card is", c2[0])
  if c2[1] > c1[1]:
    score = score - 1
    print("Enemy win! Score subtracted by a card!")
  if c1[1] > c2[1]:
    score = score + 1
    print("Player win! Enemy score subtracted by a card!")
  if c1[1] == c2[1]:
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("WAR!")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    choice = input("Click enter to draw four cards, one face up")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Your card is:" + " ", c11[0])
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("Enemy card is", c22[0])
if c22[1] > c11[1]:
  score = score - 4
print("")
print("War lost!")
print("")
if c22[1] < c11[1]:
  score = score + 4
  print("")
  print("War lost!")
  print("")
if score <= 52:
  quit()
```

Comment: I don't know if this still applies to the question asked, but now I get the error 

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
IndexError: pop from empty list**

How can I make my list a loop/infinite? I can't find a solution.

Comment: @jagmans when you pop from a list, you are shortening it by 1. You keep doing that until the list is empty in your loop. poping from an empty list throws that error. To avoid it, you can put in the while condition. replace it with `while len(deck) > 10:` since you pop index 7 after popping three times prior to it in the loop.

Comment: Also, if you want to keep doing it, you should not pop from the list and rather choose from it. `import random`  and replace pop with  
`c1=random.choice(deck))` and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much! that works perfectly. Because of the tutorial, I assumed pop was the way to go. Thanks a lot for you time and help.